Silent push notifications not working on some iOS devices
I send APNs notifications to my devices with the CloudKit dashboard. I test with two devices;
Device with Silent Push Working Successfully:
iOS version 16.5.1 (c), Model iPhone Xs
Silent Push Failed Device:
iOS version 15.3.1, Model iPhone Xr
Normal alert notifications work successfully on both devices. But I can't see any log in my project even though silent push is sent successfully on one device.
What I've Checked:

content-available is set to 1.

My app is not in kill state, it is in foreground or pending in the background.

When I send simple notifications, I can see logs in my swift project and notifications on physical devices without any problem.

No, my certificate has not expired and if there was a problem with it, I would not be able to see the normal notifications.

My phone is not in power saving mode and the “Background App Refresh” option is turned on in the app's settings.

Both devices in charging state.

App capabilities: Background Modes is enabled with Remote Notifications, Background Fetch, Background Processing.


CloudKit Dashboard After Sending Silent Push:

My AppDelegate Class In Swift Project:
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register: \(error)")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        logInfo("Received Push Notification: \(userInfo)")

        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject], aps["content-available"] as? Int == 1 {
            logInfo("This is a silent push notification")
            //DO SOME WORK
            completionHandler(.newData)
        }

        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}


